# Weird shadow behavior on mesh

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, normals, shadows, ambient-occlusion

I have some weird shadows on my objects. More specific it changes when the angle of view has changed. You can see in the first image the middle cushion is lightened and in the second image is darkened. In the middle view is the same as the others but the problem appears on the sides of the couch. I had checked already the normals (face orientation), double vertices, double faces, I don't have any modifier, smooth shading in the entire object is on, the material is simple as you can see in the fourth image, I have turned off the ambient occlusion, the size is close to normal size of a couch, I have only a point lamp (power 1000w size 1m). In the last image, you can see the appearance of the object in edit mode in render view.
I have windows 10 64 - blender 2.82
I can't get what it causes this issue.
[image: Right side view]
[[image: Left side view][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyrKK.png)
[image: middle side view]
[image: material]
[image: Edit mode]
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check for duplicated faces? Is your camera's frustrum appropriate? If you could post your file it would be helpful https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have added the blend file with textures (compressed to reduce the file size) I had checked for double faces.

Comment: It's a shame the three cushions are a single mesh, otherwise you could have flipped one over to make all three look the same. : )  If you rotate the entire cushion object so the bottom becomes the top, the light-dark-pattern gets inverted. But only if you rotate it around the x-axis, not if you rotate around the y-axis. It made me think it was a normal map UV problem but (as far as I can tell) those seem fine at first glace. (maybe they warrant closer inspection though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wrong color space for the normal map

*First of all you have some object with the normal pointing inside the surface, you can enable the Face Orientation overlay to spot them. I suggest to fix them by recalculating the normals.*

Your node setup would be correct if you were using a **common Normal Map** you can find around the web. Your normal map has been baked with different settings, as you can easily spot by comparing the shades of blue between yours (on the left) and another normal map made from a professionist.

Your is simply baked in another color space. You should ask the person who did it which one exactly is, but if you switch to **sRGB** instead of **Non-Color**, all seems fine, so we can assume sRGB is the one.

[image]

Here's some normal map from the web: your nuance is clearly lighter.

[image]

---

Solution:

Change this parameter.

[image]

Comment: You can find more ingo at https://www.creativeshrimp.com/normal-map-blender-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

The weird shading was caused due to wrong UV unwrapping . The middle one is unwrapped wrongly unwraped:[image][image][image]

It cant be corrected in blender as far as I know . I guess the textures was created in substance painter . So you gotta unwrap your mesh properly and redo it in substance painter (if i am right)

Comment: Both suggestions are interesting. I have baked them in Blender 3D, so I will unwrap them properly (the same direction for all parts) and I will try to find which settings are suitable for normal baking through the blender. I will keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Carlo
That worked
I will choose the Non-Color in the baking image slot and I can keep it for the final object as Non-color or I will turn it in sRGB in the final object as you mentioned.
I will keep the different directions of UVs for a variety.[image]